# Fancy Indexing with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, indexing

I would like to know how you might achieve this look with Apache's Indexing??
Is there a module I can get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe thats how Firefox displays FTP directories. It has nothing to do with Apache.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you ask the directory listing wigh beautiful icons.
If you want, users reach you by http://ftp.domain.tld

You can add this parameters in a .htacces

```
Options Indexes
IndexOptions FancyIndexing SuppressHTMLPreamble XHTML IconsAreLinks FoldersFirst NameWidth=* DescriptionWidth=* HTMLTable
HeaderName HEADER.html
ReadmeName FOOTER.html
IndexIgnore FOOTER.html HEADER.html ".."
IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
AddDescription "Fichier de sommes de contrôle" MD5SUMS
AddDescription "Fichier sources" *
```

The Icons should be in you icons folder  for your virtual host